# How can I select data in the same query from two different servers and databases from SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, linked-server

How can I select data in the same query from two different databases that are on two different servers, one DB2 Server and the other a SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

On your sql server, set up a linked server to the db2 database.

Then write your query on sql server.  I suggest that you use openquery for the db2 stuff.  If you have to combine the data, populate a sql server temp table with the openquery results and work from there.

The reason I suggest this is performance.  I have found that if you use this syntax

```
select somefields
from server.database.owner.table
where whatever
```

sql server will bring back the entire table from the linked server and apply the where clause afterwards.

Comment: Can't remember, but do you need two periods? **Server..database**?

Comment: @christiandev When it's a linked server, generally the syntax is **[Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]**; of course, if we're on a server, we can skip the schema in a query by typing a double period like **Database..Table**.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a linked server http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222937

[How to create a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)